# How to import and merge multiple excel files in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to import more than one hundred excel files into the environment of RStudio. The files have similar variables. I have created a directory (dir) of the excel files and then tried to use lapply to read all the files from the directory. But it always shows:

> ```
> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘barishal_sw183.xlsx’
> ```

`barishal_sw183.xlsx` is the first row in the directory and this is also the name of the first excel file of the folder the directory is referring. How can I import all these files and merge them in a single command? I also tried to use `map`, but it is not working.

```
file_list <- dir("F:/Spring 2019/Thesis_data/Kam_Thesis/data/water_level", pattern = ".xlsx")
lapply(file_list, read_excel)
```

> ```
> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘barishal_sw183.xlsx’
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you everything. The path you're passing doesn't exist. Either you set your working directory to `F:/Spring 2019/Thesis_data/Kam_Thesis/data/water_level` (`?setwd`) or you need to be passing the full paths like `F:/Spring 2019/Thesis_data/Kam_Thesis/data/water_level/barishal_sw183.xlsx` to `read_excel`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a very useful answer for a new user like me :)